# Passing "Parameters" in an Oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to understand a part of an Oracle query and also the reason why it gives error when I execute it.

The query I am looking is:

```sql
SELECT FT.*
FROM   FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER FT,
       CSTB_CONTRACT FT_CON
WHERE  FT.CONTRACT_REF_NO = FT_CON.CONTRACT_REF_NO
AND    FT.VERSION_NO    = FT_CON.LATEST_VERSION_NO
      FT
WHERE  NBRACCOUNT   = <Parameters.Account_No>
AND    datvaluedate between <Parameters.FromDate> and <Parameters.ToDate>
AND    BRANCHCODE = '010'
```

Question: I dont know how this part of the query works (in BOLD) and if the Expression used here is correct or not.

```
  NBRACCOUNT   = ** <Parameters.Account_No>**
```

AND datvaluedate between **<Parameters.FromDate> and <Parameters.ToDate>**

When I run this query it gives me below error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You cannot have two `WHERE` clauses in a statement and the line with only `FT` is not valid syntax. Also, `<Parameters.Account_No>` is not valid syntax and looks like something that should be replaced by a pre-processor in another language (i.e. possibly ColdFusion, although I think the syntax is slightly wrong for CFScript).

Comment: The Where Clause is a typo from my side. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer, you would use a parameterised query and bind variables:

```sql
SELECT FT.*
FROM   FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER FT,
       CSTB_CONTRACT FT_CON
WHERE  FT.CONTRACT_REF_NO = FT_CON.CONTRACT_REF_NO
AND    FT.VERSION_NO      = FT_CON.LATEST_VERSION_NO
AND    NBRACCOUNT         = :Account_No
AND    datvaluedate       between :FromDate and :ToDate
AND    BRANCHCODE         = '010';
```

or, substitution variables:

```sql
SELECT FT.*
FROM   FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER FT
       INNER JOIN CSTB_CONTRACT FT_CON
       ON (   FT.CONTRACT_REF_NO = FT_CON.CONTRACT_REF_NO
          AND FT.VERSION_NO      = FT_CON.LATEST_VERSION_NO )
WHERE  NBRACCOUNT         = &Account_No
AND    datvaluedate       between &FromDate and &ToDate
AND    BRANCHCODE         = '010';
```

What you have (apart from the syntax errors with too many `WHERE` clauses and the random `FT` in the middle of the query) appears to be syntax for a third-party application (such as maybe PHP or ColdFusion or something else) which pre-processes the statement and substitutes the `<>` syntax with the bind variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification on the use of Bind Variables.